# Multiple schemas on AWS Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to create multiple schemas on the same DynamoDB service in a specific region? I plan to deploy 2 applications and isolate data.

Thanks.

Meksz

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you prefix your tables with two schemas, in Java you can use both [TableNameResolver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameResolver.html) and [TableNameOverride](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.html) to ease the switch.

Comment: do you want to use the Java SDK or are you planning to use a different language?

Comment: I would use Java SDK at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to prefix easy your Dynamodb table in java instantiate the DynamoDBMapper as below :

```
      DynamoDBMapperConfig override = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig
    .TableNameOverride
    .withTableNamePrefix("enviroment"));

 DynamoDBMapperConfig config=new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT,override);

 DynamoDBMapper dbmapper= new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB,config);
```